# Why this will not output some results?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'cp_test',
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'team',
                'value'     => 'oud',
                'compare'   => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'team',
                'value'     => 'jeugd',
                'compare'   => '='
            )
        )
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $rows = get_field('wedstrijd');
            if($rows) : 
                foreach($rows as $row):
                    echo $row['stand'];
                endforeach;
            endif;
        endwhile; 
    endif;
```

This wil not return any output why? Without the meta_query it wil post all data but not with the meta_query. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The args seems to be wellformed, but you can check the construction of the arguments here https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/ to see if you are doing it well. If this is correct I would check if the metakey are written correct, and try with only one meta_query to debug that error.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the value of key 'relation' be an array, ypou should use this this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'cp_test',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => array(
            'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'team',
                'value'     => 'oud',
                'compare'   => '='
                ),
           array(
               'key'       => 'team',
               'value'     => 'jeugd',
               'compare'   => '='
           ))
       )
);
```